# How to make a transition sound so "in your face"?

Tags: arranging, electronic-music

I can't really describe well with words what I mean, but this transition in [Touch off by Uverworld](https://youtu.be/lA_hOErHD4o?t=67) (01:07) is sort of very "in your face". I feel like some techniques from electronic music are used here that I don't have to background to recognize (I'm also curious about many other sections in the song...).

What techniques used here, or how can I recreate a similar effect?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138814/discussion-on-question-by-stefan-perko-how-to-make-a-transition-sound-so-in-you).

Comment: Is it possible to not move comments that are actual comments to chat? My actual comment (clarifying the question) is/was to ask for the time stamp of the transition in question to be added in text form to the answer because following the link I don’t hear a clear transition.

Comment: @ToddWilcox it's all or nothing for comment export to chat. You can delete your own comment in chat and flag things that do not belong, but it wont typically affect the flow of a chatroom as long comment threads will typically be at most half a page of a chatroom.

Comment: @Dom - it's not "all or nothing" according to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305628/move-comments-to-chat-failed).

Comment: @ElementsinSpace he's asking about the other way. I can pick comments not to be deleted, but I can't pick comments to not be moved to chat.

Comment: @Dom - I don't have access to these tools, so I can only piece together what's possible.  But it seems like you could "move comments to chat" but not "also delete the moved comments from the post". Then, from the post manually delete the noisy comment and leave the useful comments.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace unless I'm misunderstanding, Todd is asking about things in the chat not comments here. The comments were also resolved so should be deleted anyway. The way only way not to export the comment to chat is to delete the comment first which in a long comment thread can be hard to do first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'll start with the obvious- all sound cuts out for 2 whole beats before the downbeat.  It's hard to get any more jarring than that.  And then the music comes back all at once.  You hear a sudden unmute, not natural instrument attacks.

Aside from that, electronic music often does transitions by using what people call "transition effects".  There's two parts to it- a riser, which is a sound that builds leading up to the downbeat, and an impact, which is a percussive burst of sound that happens on the downbeat.

The traditional simple riser is made by playing white noise and slowly opening up a resonant low pass filter.

The traditional impact would probably be a crash cymbal... I'm not sure.

There's plenty of ways to spice up your transition effects, but in practical terms, what most producers will do is purchase effects packs from sound designers who specialize in making weird and wonderful sounds.

I'd recommend finding some stems for a song in this genre (or, you can listen to the stems for Pendulum-Granite [here](https://splice.com/PendulumOfficial/granite)).  Listen to the "effects" stem.  See how they use noises to support the song.